# Lumia 535 camera app starting on its own

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-535, buttons

Yes, I know that Lumia 535 doesn't have dedicated camera button. But it happened to me several times already that I accidentally turned on camera app while having phone inside my pocket.

So the question here is: Is there some action which might turn on the camera while the phone itself is locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls change the camera option in the notification.
you replace the camera notification option in the slide notification with someother option(better to go with battery saver)  :)

Comment: This won't help anything since the screen isn't on.

Comment: But it actually solved my problem. After removing the camera from the notification, this stopped to happen